# Where can I find special shell extensions

Tags: windows-7, shell-extensions

Someone introduced me to a neat Windows 7 trick that’s been doing the rounds on the Internet. It enables **GodMode**, where all Windows settings into a single folder. To use it:

- Create a new folder.
- Rename the folder to GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

This got me thinking ...

Where could I find other custom extensions that might be interesting?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider making this community wiki?

Comment: Good idea, there is no "right" answer, just interesting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "Godmode Maker" one lets you **choose from over 50 "Deities"** :)

**Be A Windows God With Go GodMode**

> As you probably know, GodMode provides
>   quick access to an operating system's
>   more or less hidden controls (Windows
>   Vista/Seven). How does that work? You
>   have to create a folder with a certain
>   string (GUID) at the end.
>
> But that can be pretty hard and, even,
>   unaesthetic. Why? Well, it can get
>   pretty hard to create a lot of them
>   (considering the large number of
>   GodModes out there). Furthermore, that
>   GUID doesn't look very nice on your
>   desktop.
>
> This is where **[Go GodMode](http://apps.nozavi.com/go-godmode-overview)** enters the
>   scene: This small app will help you
>   create over 50 GodModes just by
>   selecting them and pressing the GO
>   button. It also provides a few cool
>   options:
>
> Instead of creating the folders on
>   your desktop, you can create them in a
>   folder on your computer and just
>   create a shortcut on your desktop. You
>   can also add shortcuts to the Start
>   Menu, QuickLaunch and Favorites
>   folder.
>
> You can **add GodModes to folder and desktop context menus** without even
>   adding a single file or folder to your
>   harddrive!

[image]

Comment: This is actually pretty cool!